# Upsert/Append to SQL database using SQL Alchemy/Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, sql-server, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy

I'm using Python 3.11 and SSMS 19.

Once again, I'm running into a ton of fun with my project. I've gotten it working reasonably well, but I realize now that it isn't updating, just adding the same lines over and over into my database. Meaning it rejects all of the entries if a primary key matches, and if I remove the PK constraint, it doesn't update, it just adds a new line.

Edit:
Just for clarification, I want to do this by column, not by row or entry. If I have to add each update individually, I might as well not even write the program, as I would be writing update lines for ~300 rows every 3 days. I need the code to go line by line by itself, and either update, merge, or ignore depending on the column.

Here's what's working right now, I have the engine/connection created through SQLAlchemy.

```
fulldf.to_sql('Shortage',engine, if_exists='append', index=False, chunksize=200, dtype={'Priority': BigInteger,
                                                               'PN':String(255),
                                                               'Part_Type': Text,
                                                               'MPN': Text,
                                                               'Proposed_MPN': Text,
                                                               'Distributor': String(100),
                                                               'Reason_for_Add': Text,
                                                               'Line_Down': Date,
                                                               'Engineering-Samples_Available': Text,
                                                               'Build_Samples-Available': Text,
                                                               'Comments': Text,                                                                                       
                                                               'Supplier_Comments': Text,
                                                               'Circuit_Location': Text,
                                                               'Last_Updated': Date
```

This works awesome for the initial table, and if I didn't have any Primary Key repeats. Unfortunately I do and I will, so it's not great for that.

My primary key (constrained in SQL, not here for ease of use) is 'PN', of which all are unique.
Some columns like 'Part_Type','MPN','Distributor', etc I just want to be overwritten/ignored. Those values shouldn't change and if they do, that will be a case-by-case basis.

For the Date columns, I want the old date removed and the other added in, which I believe can be accomplished with if_exists='update' or perhaps if_exists='replace'? Either way, that wont be too much of a hurdle.

As an afterthought- I really don't care about SQL injection here. This program is going to be used by roughly 5 trusted people on the local intranet, and if someone really wants to blow up a simple (unnecessary for production) database, they're more than welcome to. I'd rather not complicate something when I don't need to.

I've tried a few things, namely this upsert method:

https://blog.alexparunov.com/upserting-update-and-insert-with-pandas

Which does not work for me as my laptop is locked down harder than Fort Knox, so PostgreSQL and psycopg2 can't initialize. And yes, I've tried installed psycopg2-binary.

I'm just needing some guidance and haven't found much on here.

Edit:
Here's an example for clarity of what I'm looking to do:

I have this entry in the dataframe:

```
P/N:        Supplier_Comments:      Comments:
1-100116    "6-27-23 Review with Holly  "24000 reserved
```

and then I have the part that's already in the database:

```
P/N:        Supplier_Comments:      Comments:
1-100116    "6-29-23: Shipping 24k Oct" "Next Dock Date 7/31"
```

I need it to become:

```
P/N:        Supplier_Comments:      Comments:
1-100116    "6-27-23 Review with Holly  "24000 reserved
        6-29-23: Shipping 24k Oct"  "Next Dock Date 7/31"
```

NOT

```
1-100116    "6-27-23 Review with Holly  "24000 reserved 
1-100116    "6-29-23: Shipping 24k Oct" "Next Dock Date 7/31"
```

I also don't want to combine different primary keys, either. I just want primary keys that already exist to be joined with the SQL entry.

I want this to be done automatically, without me having to go through the rows to find which primary keys already exist in the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.to_sql()` to upload the updates to a temporary table and then use MERGE to update the main table.

```py
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa

engine = sa.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://scott:tiger^5HHH@mssql_199")

# set up environment for this example
with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.exec_driver_sql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Shortage")
    conn.exec_driver_sql(
        """\
    CREATE TABLE Shortage (
    PN varchar(255) primary key,
    Part_Type varchar(50),
    Comments varchar(max)
    )
    """
    )
    conn.exec_driver_sql(
        """\
    INSERT INTO Shortage (PN, Part_Type, Comments)
    VALUES ('Part_A', 'original type', 'A comment.')
    """
    )

# update the table
fulldf = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ("Part_A", "updated type", "Another comment."),
        ("Part_B", "some other type", "This is a new part."),
    ],
    columns=["PN", "Part_Type", "Comments"],
)
with engine.begin() as conn:
    fulldf.to_sql("#temp_table", conn, if_exists="replace", index=False)
    conn.exec_driver_sql(
        """\
    MERGE Shortage WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS main
    USING (SELECT PN, Part_Type, Comments FROM #temp_table) AS temp
    ON (main.PN = temp.PN)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE SET 
        Part_Type = temp.Part_Type, 
        Comments = main.Comments + ' ' + temp.Comments
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT (PN, Part_Type, Comments) VALUES (temp.PN, temp.Part_Type, temp.Comments);
    """
    )

# check results
print(pd.read_sql_table("Shortage", engine))
"""
       PN        Part_Type                     Comments
0  Part_A     updated type  A comment. Another comment.
1  Part_B  some other type          This is a new part.
"""
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. Picking out specific rows, which requires me to go through the sheets (there are 3 of them) would defeat the purpose of this program. Is there a way I can do this without identifying duplicate rows? There can be up to 400 entries per sheet, and it wouldn't be time effective to edit my code for every sheet that comes in. Can I do this by just defining columns to insert?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "picking out specific rows", "do this by column, not by row or entry" and "without identifying duplicate rows".

Comment: I'll give you an example in the edit.

Comment: "I want this to be done automatically, without me having to go through the rows to find which primary keys already exist in the database." - That's exactly what MERGE does. Have another look at my example. Notice that the new Comment for Part_A (from the data in fulldf) is appended to the existing one (from the example setup code)

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry about that. I misread the output there. Thank you.